# AWS EC2: Do I need to run "aws configure" to assign access keys to if my instance already has an IAM role?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, aws-cli

I'm fairly new to AWS. I'm setting up an EC2 instance (an Ubuntu 18.04 LAMP server).

I've installed [the aws CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/cli/) on the instance, so I can automate EBS snapshots for backup.

I've also created an IAM role with the needed permissions to run `aws ec2 create-snapshot`, and I've assigned this role to my EC2 instance.

My question: is there any need to run `aws configure` on the EC2 instance, in order to set the AWS Access Key ID and AWS Secret Access Key? I'm still wrapping my head around AWS IAM roles – but (since the EC2 instance has a role), it sounds like the instance will acquire the needed keys from IAM automagically. Therefore, I assume that there's never any need to run `aws configure`. (In fact, it seems like this would be counterproductive, since the keys set via `aws configure` [would override](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html#config-settings-and-precedence) the keys acquired automatically via the role.)

Is all of that accurate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the AWS CLI will progress through a list of credential providers. The instance metadata service will eventually be reached, even if you have not configured the AWS cli:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html#config-settings-and-precedence

And yes, if you add keys to the AWSCLI config file, they will be used with higher priority than those obtained from the instance metadata service.